# Appropriate regression when multiple dependent values for same independent value

Tags: regression

I have a data set which looks as following:

```
    Y
1   2
1   1.5
1   2.5
2   5
2   3
3   5.2
3   6
3   6.8
4   6
4   7
```

And the corresponding plot is:

[image]

What kind of regression is appropriate for the above kind of data ?

Comment: I think OLS should work fine on this. Effectively it will try to fit a line through the "midpoints" of the cluster of y values having the same x value, with a bigger weight for the bigger clusters. Presumably that is what you want.

Answer (score 1):

As noob2 suggested, you run a simple OLS regression (in Excel). You get the estimation result $$\hat{y}_i=0.63+1.61x_i$$ with an $R^2=0.84$. That seems to do the job!

You may want to read [this](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/353258/linear-regression-with-multiple-y-values-per-x-and-their-arithmetic-means) about aggregating the $y_i$ values for the same $x_i$ observation.

[image]